# Sort Objects That Meet Threshold

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects returned by the database that I am attempting to run a sort() on.

```
[{
  PER_ID: 5511,
  DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG: '353',
  DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED: 118,
},
{
  PER_ID: 5016,
  DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG: '372',
  DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED: 109,
},{
  PER_ID: 4181,
  DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG: '359',
  DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED: 73,
},
{
  PER_ID: 5016,
  DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG: '372',
  DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED: 109,
},{
  PER_ID: 158,
  DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG: '370',
  DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED: 1112,
}]
```

I'd like to get the value of PER_ID for the object with the lowest value for DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG where also DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED >= 10.

The code I have is:

```
per_recs = per_recs.sort(function (prior, curr) {

  return ((curr.DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED >= 10 && (prior.DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG - curr.DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG > 0) ? 1 : 0));

});

let per_id_with_lowest_deal_time_to_present_mins_biz_avg = per_recs[0].PER_ID;
```

Comment: the sort function is not stable. If DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED is present on prior and not on current it must return -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify your problem and filter out the elements that do not interest you first, like that :

```
const items = [{
  PER_ID: 5511,
  DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG: '353',
  DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED: 118,
},
{
  PER_ID: 5016,
  DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG: '372',
  DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED: 109,
},{
  PER_ID: 4181,
  DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG: '359',
  DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED: 9,
},
{
  PER_ID: 5016,
  DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG: '372',
  DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED: 109,
},{
  PER_ID: 158,
  DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG: '370',
  DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED: 1112,
}]

const sortedItems = items
 .filter(item => item.DEAL_COUNT_PRESENTED >= 10)
 .sort((a, b) => {
   return +a.DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG - +b.DEAL_TIME_TO_PRESENT_MINS_BIZ_AVG
 })

let foundItem = sortedItems[0].PER_ID;
```

Here you go !

Comment: You're right, I had to simplify my life with filter() and then it's so clear.

Answer (score 1):

To get the a small number m (1) from n entries a top-m heap sort is usually more efficient. For 1 it is even shorter as a simple `reduce` can be used (the accumulator represents the heap):

```
const lowest = records.reduce((current, entry) => 
  entry.count >= 10 && (!current || entry.avg < current.avg) ? entry : current, null);
```